# Best way to aggregate multiple rank correlation coefficients? (Kendall Tau)

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I am testing a search engine which operates over a corpus of documents. For simplicity, let's say the corpus is quite small and consists of only fifteen docs, like *d1, d2, d3, ... , d15*. And, as an additional simplification, any algorithm we test will produce an ordering of all 15 of these docs.

Now let's say I have a test algorithm *T* and an idealized algorithm *I*, which produce the following results for a given query *Q1*

`T(Q1) = 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15`

and

`I(Q1) = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15`

(For this toy example, the results of the two algorithms are very similar and differ only in the swapping of the first two results).

**First Question:** What is the best statistical method for measuring the "similarity" of these two algorithms. I have been directed towards the Kendall Tau rank correlation coefficient, which I am using like so:

```
>>> stats.kendalltau(
...     [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
...     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
... )
KendalltauResult(correlation=0.980952380952381, pvalue=2.294149119545945e-11)
```

This seems very reasonable and exactly what I want!

**Second Question:** But now, the hard part. I would like to **aggregate** my measure of similarity between the two algorithms **across many queries** (*Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, ...*). What is the best way to aggregate many individual rank correlation coefficients into a single consolidated measure?

At high level, my ultimate goal is to produce a single, quantitative measure of similarity for two different algorithms with respect to a fixed query set and corpus. Thank you!

Comment: can your algorithms T and I just rank everything and you compute the Kendall Tau coefficient using the rankings of all queries? or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Well you would have a Kendall Tau for Q1, then a KT(Q2), KT(Q3), KT(Q4), etc.... So you have the individual correlation coefficients for all the queries. What's the best way to coalesce or aggregate them to a single measure?

Comment: Do you have any reason to not simply use the arithmetic mean?

Comment: I'd be happy to use arithmetic mean, I just wasn't sure if there was some more "proper" strategy (or if I needed to consider some details/risks). Do you think that's best?

Comment: @MikeRepass what I am saying is: can't you have one Kendall Tau for Q1, Q2, etc? That is, put all the queries together, have your algorithms rank them and then calculate one Kendall Tau.

Comment: @Schach21 I fear in that case the result would be different based on the ordering of the Qs. So Q1Q2Q3 could produce a very different result from Q3Q1Q2, which feels wrong. It'd be great if the aggregation did not have an ordering dependency on the queries

Comment: An obvious weakness of Kendall's tau for your purpose is that it ignores the order of the results. You'll get exactly the same correlation if you swap results 14 and 15 even though they are further down the list.

Comment: @dipetkov It took me a second read to understand. I think you mean it ignores the position, relevance, possibly the weight (if any) of the rankings.